# Schengen visa Bank balance and funds parking related question

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, schengen-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am going to Europe this August and wish to apply for visa from Dutch consulate in May. I have recently started looking out for the bank balance I need into my account.

I have understood that I shouldn't add lot of money into my account otherwise it could be considered as funds parking, but to this I want to check , can I not add surplus cash I have with me of around 75K INR to my account ?

Also generally my wife transfers me some money from time to time, like I've paid for her flight tickets and she will transfer that amount to me. Will transfers within my family also cause an issue?

Lastly if these transfers cause an issue then how can I convince the visa authorities that it is actually my money being deposited and my wife whose transferring for money to me why she owes me.

P.S, it's almost 3 months left for my visa, if I do add the money now and it stays in my account for 3 months and I hope it's not considered as funds parking.

Comment: Hi, no this is not a duplicate. I don't have information on how to transfer funds and provide documentation to show that it is actually my money!

Comment: You need to be able to demonstrate that any large deposits are legitimate. If you want to claim that a certain deposit is your wife repaying you for money that you spent, that should be easy: your wife transfers money into your account on one day and you point out the transaction from the previous day/week/whatever that she's paying you back for.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, How can i point that out? when my wife is transferring me the money, if she adds a comment "Payment for Flight ticket to Amsterdam Amount " suffice?

Comment: @JayeshMulwani You could include your wife's bank statement and a note linking the two transactions.

Answer (score 3):

What they are looking for is a **stable, explained** income which exceeds the **reasonable** expenses. They expect tourists to pay for a vacation out of their salary (or, for young people, from the parents or similar relatives), not with money arriving out of thin air. And they expect business travelers to be in a stable economic situation.

This pattern is more important than the balance. Can you show a good income/expenditure pattern with your bank statements?

[This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) talks about the UK, but the principle is the same.

Comment: I had already gone through the suggested question, I want to know if me depositing money into my own account is a problem for them? Also if my wife transfers money into my account for tickets which I booked from my credit card is that also a problem , If yes, how can I tackle it?

Comment: First, make sure that there is enough steady income for your trip *without* the family deposits. Second, explain everything. Have the ticket transfer match exactly half the ticket costs. Deposits can be a problem if they come out of nowhere.

Comment: @Jayesh Mulwani The fundamental rule is to provide evidence of the source of all out of the ordinary deposits into your account. Eg If your wife transfers money in, demonstrate where it came from via her bank statements and salary slips. If you’ve got spare cash that you can’t explain, use it to pay for things rather than deposit it in your account. It’s generally best to provide 6 months’ worth of statements so IMHO it’s already too late trying to get your 75k INR into your account without risking a funds parking-based refusal

Comment: @Traveller, Thank you, i ask this because i have recently switched jobs and didn't have any salary inflow for the past two months(notice period issues) and that's why bank account balance looks bad..

How about depositing the amount into my other bank account and transferring amount from there to the account which i'm going to use for Visa hoping it would show my own name from where the money has come and wont be a problem?

Comment: @Jayesh Mulwani That won’t work - you’ll still have to provide statements for your other bank account and show where the deposit into that account came from. You basically can’t get this lump sum cash deposit into your account without proving its source. Trying to do it is an even bigger funds parking risk if the 75k INR is out of line with your normal income/savings, or it’s a large portion of the amount you say you have available to spend on the trip. The sudden appearance of unexplained ‘surplus cash’ is a classic red flag for an ECO

Comment: @Traveller, What if this deposit was done over a span of time in small chunks of 20k, will it still bother them? 
My salary is more than 80K, so its not like its a very significant sum i'll be adding..
Even 4 deposits*20K INR made in a span of 2 months will cause a red flag?

Comment: @Jayesh Mulwani It’s almost equivalent to one months’ salary so I’d say it’s significant no matter how you try to deposit it. If this is your first application you can expect a lot of scrutiny.

Comment: @Traveller, Actually this is my second Application for Schengen visa, earlier one was a Business visa and was sponsored by my firm. This time it will be a Tourist trip and i will have NOC from my employer stating that i'll be on vacation.