# Schengen requirement for bank balance- throughout 3 month period or closing balance?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am travelling with my sister to the Netherlands, but she is applying through the Spanish consulate in London because she will be travelling to Spain after Amsterdam and that's her main destination as she will be there for one more day than the Netherlands.

There is a requirement that £724 balance must show in her account.
I wanted to know whether this means that the balance should not have been lower than £724 at any point in the previous three months, or whether the £724 needs to be the closing balance.

In February and March she had very low balance, but from September to January and again in April, she has had a good balance. She moved some more money from her savings into her current account in the UK and now has had more than £724 in there for about 2 weeks.

Could anyone advise whether the requirement is to maintain the funds for the entire period of the statements or the closing balance?
The information on the internet is not very clear on this.

She has more money in savings but they ask for current accounts.
For four out of six months, she had a good balance. March and February were low.

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131626/schengen-visa-bank-balance-and-funds-parking-related-question . Do go through the linked UK question there to understand why they ask for bank statements and why final amount is not so important.

Comment: If she has more money in another account that belongs to her, it would be best if she included that as well. The purpose is to show that you have sufficient funds (and they will be very skeptical of someone who appears to be spending their entire savings on a trip, or who is getting mysterious large deposits from unknown sources), so you're not doing your application any favors if you submit bank statements with a very low balance when you actually have a bunch of money elsewhere.

Comment: Include statements from her savings, certainly the months where she moved money to her current account and the months since.

Comment: I don't know if a savings account is considered "current" but it's easy enough to transfer money from it. I would guess non-current accounts would be retirement accounts, CDs, other non-liquid accounts.

Comment: Thank you for your message. I know someone who took a savings statement and VFS apparently refused to accept the application. My sister transferred money from her savings to current account, so we're thinking of submitting both statements.

Answer (score 9):

As stated in the comments its the closing balance that they will be looking at to ensure enough funds are there to cover your stay, but you should include all relevant statements.

As she has moved money from her savings into her 'current' account you need to show where that money has come from so it doesn't look like funds parking which can look suspicious and negatively impact your application. By also submitting the savings account information you can show that the transfer came from her own money, and it is available for her to use during your stay, so ensure to submit both for any relevant months.